# Is there an elegant way to assign nullable types to optional parameters?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function:

```
fun leftPad(value: String, length: Int = 3, char: Char = ' '): String = value.padStart(length, char)
```

Is there a way to be able to invoke this and pass values with nullable types to the optional parameters as in:

```
length: Int? = getLength()
char: Char? = getChar()
leftPad(value, length = length, char = char)
```

The only workaround I've tried is the following:

```
fun leftPad(value: String, length: Int? = null, char: Char? = null): String {
        val length = length ?: 4
        val char = char ?: ' '
        return value.padStart(length, char)
    }
```

It does what I want, but the name shadowed warning irks me a little.

Comment: Currently, there's no way to tell the compiler to do what you want. You either pass anything as the value for a parameter, and then the default value is not evaluated during the call, or you don't pass an argument for it, and then the default value is evaluated. Your workaround seems to be the best way to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name shadowed warning is just saying that your `val length` shadows the `length` parameter in the method. To eliminate it, either inline the defaults or rename your local variables. For example:

```
fun leftPad(value: String, length: Int? = null, char: Char? = null): String {
    return value.padStart(length ?: 4, char ?: ' ')
}
```

or

```
fun leftPad(value: String, length: Int? = null, char: Char? = null): String {
    val resolvedLength = length ?: 4
    val resolvedChar = char ?: ' '
    return value.padStart(resolvedLength, resolvedChar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of *elegant* but it's possible to do something with reflection.

Below is a way (`construct`) to apply a Map of arguments to the primary constructor, and a second way (`constructNullIsDefault`) that filters out the `null` values before applying the map (and some syntactic sugar with a vararg of `Pair` to avoid having to construct a Map yourself for each call)

```
inline fun <reified X : Any> constructNullIsDefault(vararg arguments: Pair<String, Any?>): X? {
    return construct(arguments.toMap().filterValues { it != null } as Map<String, Any>)
}

inline fun <reified X : Any> construct(arguments: Map<String, Any>): X? {
    val klass = X::class
    val constructor = klass.primaryConstructor!!
    val parameters = constructor.parameters
    val parameterMap =
        arguments.map { argument -> parameters.find { it.name == argument.key }!! to argument.value }.toMap()
    return constructor.callBy(parameterMap)
}

@Test
fun testAbc() {
    val x = "hello"
    val y = null as String?

    val abc = constructNullIsDefault<Abc>("x" to x, "y" to y)
    println(abc)
}
```